# VBA code with Object required error

Tags: excel, vba

Code has error. When I debug, it shows the error of last line.

```
Sub test()
    WB_Master = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Dim ra As Range
    open file
    Workbooks.Open FileName:="X:\Projects\RPOC\Comparison\book1.xlsx"
    WB_Source = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Workbooks(WB_Source).Activate
    Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
    ' set value to ra. Is it correct?
    Set ra = Range("c2")

    Workbooks(WB_Source).Close SaveChanges:=False


    Workbooks(WB_Master).Activate

    Worksheets("sheet1").Activate

    Set Range("k2").Value = ra.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `Set` a `Value` - you should only use the `Set` keyword when assigning an object reference.  (E.g. your `Set ra = Range("c2")` is assigning a reference to `Range("c2")` to your object `ra`.)

So change

```
Set Range("k2").Value = ra.Value
```

to

```
Range("k2").Value = ra.Value
```

---

Because you are also closing the workbook that contains the range referred to by your `ra` variable before you use it, you will also have problems.  I have refactored your code to get around that issue:

```
Sub test()
    Dim WB_Source As Workbook
    Dim WB_Master As Workbook

    Set WB_Master = ActiveWorkbook
    Set WB_Source = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="X:\Projects\RPOC\Comparison\book1.xlsx")

    WB_Master.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("k2").Value = _
        WB_Source.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("c2").Value

    WB_Source.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

(Note: I changed your `WB_Source` and `WB_Master` variables from being `Variant/String` to being `Workbook`.)

Comment: I think it is assigning `Range("c2")` object reference to a variable range `ra`.

Comment: @zhenhao Ohhh - You are closing the workbook first!  I didn't notice that.  Just a second and I will update the answer.

Comment: @YowE3K By the way, if I use this method to read data from several files ( about 500), which have the same format,     +9will it be slow?

Comment: @zhenhao Yes, to open 500 files and read a single value from each one will be slow.  You should consider whether your data structure (one important number in 500 workbooks) is appropriate for what you are doing.  (If you have 500 offline users, each with their own workbook, and they each send you a copy of their file and you are then trying to create a summary - maybe it is the best way.  But I can't think of many other scenarios where it would make sense.)